# c# code to set an attribute of a class of a group of controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have researched but none of the direct method was found to do this task.what i am trying to do is,i have some asp:textboxes which have same class

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtItemAmnt5"  class="totaltextbox" runat="server" Width="106px"></asp:TextBox>
```

and with the help of c# code i want to hide all the textboxes which belongs to the same class.one of the indirect approach is this, which is irritating. does any one have smarter code

```
 for (int j =1 ; j <=9 ; j++)
        {

            TextBox objtxt = this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("txt"+j.ToString()) as TextBox;

            objtxt.Visible= true;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

It will hide all elements with class 'totaltextbox'.

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "for (let el of document.querySelectorAll('.totaltextbox')) el.style.visibility = 'hidden';", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recomend to do it in client side using Javascript, you get better performance and can do it using 1 line of code using jquery for instance:

```
$(".myClass").hide();
```

https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/